# need an easier way to initialize nested hashes in ruby rather than assignment at each deeper level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to the ruby landscape and have found a lot of difficulty working with hashes. It seems there are a lot of ways to do the same thing in ruby, but what I'm having trouble with is assigning hashes at sub levels in an existing hash.

For example in my class I have the following code:

```
@query_hash = {"term" => {"field" => "value"}
@main_hash["query"]["filtered"]["query"]["bool"] = @query_hash
```

The problem is that there are times where one of the sub-hashes are missing in the `@main_hash` so the above path would have a key such as `"filtered"` or `"query"` missing in `@main_hash` and I'd get a nil related exception. So what I have had to do is check for each level of nestation first before referencing the next as I go deeper in the hash. If the level doesn't exist I have to initialize that sub-hash in an ugly way like this: `@main_hash["query"] = {"filtered" => {"query" => "bool"}}`

Is there a more cleaner and simpler way to deal with this kind of hash munging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is merely a generalization of @Ryan Bigg's answer.

Suppose:

```
main_hash   = { "query1"=>
                 { "filtered"=>
                   { "query2"=>"value" }
                 }
              }
nested_keys = ["query1", "filtered", "cat", "dog"]
query_hash  = { "term"=>
                { "field"=>"value" }
              }
```

Then:

```
nested_keys.reduce(main_hash) { |h,k|
  h[k].is_a?(Hash) ? h[k] : h[k] = {} }.update(query_hash) 
main_hash
  #=> { "query1"=>
  #     { "filtered"=>
  #       { "query2"=> "value",
  #         "cat"=>
  #           { "dog"=>
  #             {"term"=>
  #               {"field"=>"value"}
  #             }
  #           }
  #       }
  #     }
  #   }
```

Notice that `h[k].is_a?(Hash)` serves double-duty: it both checks that `h` has a key `k` and if it does, whether `h[k]` is a hash.

Answer (score 3):

The `merge` method is built for this kind of thing!

```
@main_hash = { "not_query" => "something else" }

@main_hash.merge!(
  "query" => {
    "filtered" => {
      "query" => {
        "bool" => {
          "term" => { "field" => "value" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```

The `@main_hash` after this call will now be this:

```
{"not_query"=>"something else", "query"=>{"filtered"=>{"query"=>{"bool"=>{"term"=>{"field"=>"value"}}}}}}
```

Comment: I'm puzzled why you made this so specific, as it would be more useful and not much more difficult to make it general (using `reduce`, for example), for an arbitrary key-value pair and location in the hash.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I await your answer with the `reduce` example so that I can learn from it.

Comment: I couldn't shoehorn it into a comment, so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create the Hash with a default proc that initializes missing values to subhashes with the same default proc:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) } #=> {}
h['a']['b']['c'] = 'd'
h #=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>"d"}}}
```

Here's how that works.

When you create a new Hash with `Hash.new` (instead of just using `{}`), you can pass either a default value, or a default proc.

If you pass a value, then any time you ask the hash for a key that doesn't exist, you get that value back:

```
irb(main):001:0> counts = Hash.new(0)  #=> {}
irb(main):002:0> counts[:somekey] #=> 0
```

Note that this doesn't actually insert the key into the hash, though:

```
irb(main):003:0> counts.keys #=> []
```

Which means that any sort of non-assignment-based modification won't work like you might expect:

```
lists = Hash.new([]);
%w<a b c b>.each do |k| lists[k].push k end
lists  #=> {}
```

Each time you try to access `lists[k]` it returns the empty list, and appends to that list, but that list is not assigned back to `lists[k]`, so the hash stays empty.

This is where the default *proc* comes in handy. Instead of passing a value, you pass a block of code, and that block of code is run every time you access a key that doesn't exist. The return value of the block is returned just like a default value, but the code can have side effects, including modifying the hash (which is passed as the first argument to the proc).

```
lists = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = [] }
%w<a b c b>.each do |k| lists[k].push k end
lists # => {"a"=>["a"], "b"=>["b", "b"], "c"=>["c"]}
```

That's what I did to solve the problem: I assigned a default proc that stores and returns a new hash. But not just any new hash - it's a new hash with the same default proc as the containing hash, so that you can go as deep as you want with a single expression and it does the right thing.

Comment: Nice one, Mark. And then after you have `h #=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>"d"}}}`, `h['a']['x']['c'] = 'y'` results in `h
#=> {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>"d"}, "x"=>{"c"=>"y"}}}`.

Comment: Not too good with procs if you can explain further that would be really helpful